# Spring: detached entity passed to persist thrown by JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm creating a little project and trying mainly to learn spring.
I have two entities one of them is User and the another one is Client.

This is the User entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_sequence", sequenceName = "user_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_sequence")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }

// getter and setters
```

This is the Client entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client {
    @Id
    private Long userId;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_clients_users"))
    private User user;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Client() {
    }

    public Client(User user, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber) {
        this.user = user;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

//getter and setters..
```

I have both services for these entities with normal functionality that write into the database.

```
    @Transactional
    public Client createClient(Client client) {
        return clientRepository.save(client);
    }
```

```
    @Transactional
    public User createUser(User user) {
         return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

In the main class I'm creating an object of CommandLineRunner, the idea was to
test the entities and see if everything works fine but when I try to save the user
first and then use it to save the client I'm getting the error: detached entity passed to persist: com....

```
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(UserService userService, ClientService clientService,
                                 TechnicianService service, JobService jobService) {
        return args -> {
        User clientUser = new User("kris", "password", "testemail@gmail.com");

        clientUser = userService.createUser(clientUser);

            Client client = new Client(clientUser,"Kristiyan","Kristiyanov","09999999999");
            clientService.createClient(client);

        };
    }
```

I fixed the problem by removing this line.

`clientUser = userService.createUser(clientUser);`

And save only the client, it works, it also creates rows in both user and client table which is good but why I am getting this error when I try first to save it in the user table and then to the client one and how I can manage to do that?

Edit:
There is a logic in this thing because if the method createClient(), creates a row in both client and user table, why I have to call createUser(), if this practically happen it will write one more row in the user table and we don't want that (plus that the username and the emails are unique so it won't happen anyway), the idea is to first create the user, use it and after this if I want to connect him to the client table also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions are your problem here. createClient() and createUser() each run in their own isolated transaction. The sequence of events which will happen thus is:

- createUser(); CREATE TRANSACTION; persist user to database; user becomes a *managed entity*; END TRANSACTION
- user is at this point *detached*, because the transaction it was part of is now closed. This is what is causing your misery.

- createClient(); CREATE TRANSACTION; persist client to database; Bang.

At this point it fails, because the user inside the client is a detached entity, it is not attached to the transaction which is currently running for the createClient() call.

There are a number of ways to deal with that and the JPA specification would be a good place to visit to learn about the EntityManager (something that Spring is hiding from you here), first and second level cache, refreshing entities, persist VS merge, etc.

In this particular case, the design of the code does not seem correct. You create the user and the client in unison, so they should be part of one transaction so that when something fails, all work is rolled back and not just half of it. In your example if user persistence would succeed, but client persistence would fail, the user is still created in the database but no client to go along with it.

So a solution would be to have one method with one transaction. Here is an untested example:

```
@Transaction
public Client createUserWithClient(User user, Client client) {
  user = userRepository.save(user);
  client.setUser(user);

  return clientRepository.save(client);
}
```

This is just to demonstrate the problem you are facing; the simplest solution is to use the one you already found; persist the client only and have it cascade persist the user for you. In your scenario there really is not much use to persist the user and client in isolation from each other.

Comment: "In your example if user persistence would succeed, but client persistence would fail, the user is still created in the database but no client to go along with it." - 
That's the idea I want to persist the user only and after that if I want to persist him in the second table "client" while adding additional information. The idea is that one user can be "client" but another user can be for example "seller".

Comment: Doesn't matter; you still don't want a user to exist without either a client OR a seller also existing. So the persistence needs to happen in one transaction.